# Birt Reports with asp.net

Tags: java, asp.net, sql-server, eclipse, birt

I am currently forced to use Birt as a reporting tool in an application I build. I didn't want to make it overly complicated, because the feature-set is very small, but my client told me he wanted Birt - there's no way around that. Except for that I can use whatever I want.

Because I need some other data from the MSSQL-Server, I would love to use asp.net core. Someone told me that there was a way of just running Birt in tomcat and then referencing the reports out of my application. I'm completely new to Birt and my experience with asp.net is limited.

I really hope someone understands my dilemma and can help me.

Comment: Asking for tutorials/guides is EXPLICITLY off-topic. We are not here to be your tutors.

Comment: Changed it. Sorry about that.